# Rails rake db uninitialized constant Faker::User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

So i have been trying to reset and migrate my data using the line

```
rake db:reset db:migrate
```

It seemed to be going through since the database is dropped then another one is created but i get a **rake aborted!**

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Faker::User
```

Comment: You ran `bundle install` before `rake ...`?

Comment: Do you use the `faker` gem in your application? How do you use it? Especially in the line in which the exception is raised?

Comment: In your `Gemfile`, you might have this line: `require: false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing  `Faker::User.username` from my seeds.rb file did the job.